# Selenium C# List

Tags: c#, list, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**Hello Stackoverflow Users,**

I have a internet site with 99 list elements. 
The diffrence between the elements are only the names.

```
<li class="_6e4x5">
  <div class="_npuc5">
    <div class="_f5wpw">
      <div class="_eryrc">
        <div class="_2nunc">
          <a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8" title="Name1" href="/"Name1/">"Name1</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

[...]

<li class="_6e4x5">
  <div class="_npuc5">
    <div class="_f5wpw">
      <div class="_eryrc">
        <div class="_2nunc">
          <a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8" title="Name99" href="/"Name99/">"Name99</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

**What I want:**

I want to take the "title" of each list element and put it in a new list.

**What I tried:**

```
List<string> following = new List<string>();

By name = By.XPath("//div[@class='_2nunc']");

IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

IList<IWebElement> displayedOptions = driver.FindElements(name);

foreach (IWebElement option in displayedOptions)
{
  string temp = displayedOptions[i].ToString();
  following.Add(temp);
  i++;
}
```

If I run the code, I only get the element ID, and not the "title" (name34 for example). I hope you have enough information to help me with my problem. Thanks in advance for every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `take the` **title** `of each list element and put it in a new list` you can use the following code block :

```
List<string> following = new List<string>();
IList<IWebElement> displayedOptions = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//li[@class='_6e4x5']//a[@class='_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8']"));
foreach (IWebElement option in displayedOptions)
{
    string temp = option.GetAttribute("title");
    following.Add(temp);
}
```

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: "invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //li[@class='_6e4x5'//a[@class='_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//li[@class='_6e4x5'//a[@class='_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to get the `a` element's `title` [attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_attribute). The selenium `IWebElement` interface has a [`GetAttribute`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) method you can use to get the title of your elements.

```
foreach (IWebElement option in displayedOptions)
{
  following.Add(option.GetAttribute("title"));
}
```

Comment: the following list is filled with empty strings